# How can I determine what this shield with an icon is on my macOS menu bar?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, icon, menu-bar

This icon just appeared on my macbook menu bar. I tried to remove it by command + drag but that does not work to get rid of it.

[image: picture of macOS menu bar with a shield like icon and x inside]

How do I understand what it is and then delete it?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the Sophos Antivirus 'update failed' icon.

Ref: [Sophos Anti-Virus for Mac menu bar shields](https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/122666)